# Set logscale for y axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have used `facet_wrap` to build my plot as picture below:

[image]

After considering abit, I have used `scale_y_log10` to transform my data (4 panels in the plot). [image]

However, I realized that I only need to do the transformation for the first panel not the others since those values are very closed to `0`.

My idea is to separate those values I would like to transform and combine them later on. I wondering that whether I can use `scale_y_log10` for only one single panel created by `facet_wrap` so that I dont have to separate my dataset.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/reference/facetted_pos_scales.html

Comment: @stefan do you want to write an answer, then I will accept for you!